# GID for new user is not taking system default value 100?

Tags: linux, user-accounts

New user is not taking system default Group ID. System default group id for new user is 100.
Whenever i create a new user, GID as well as UID increments by 1.
I can understand UID but GID should be 100 for every new user.
What is the possible reason?
I am using Amazon linux AMI on EC2.

```
# adduser -D
GROUP=100
HOME=/home
INACTIVE=-1
EXPIRE=
SHELL=/bin/bash
SKEL=/etc/skel
CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=yes

# useradd -m testuser
# useradd -m testuser2

# cat /etc/passwd
testuser:x:501:503::/home/testuser:/bin/bash
testuser2:x:502:504::/home/testuser2:/bin/bash
```

Comment: I'm not sure about AMI, but on some OSes, adduser is actually a separate Perl wrapper script for useradd. Try using `adduser` instead when actually adding the user to see if that has any effect.

Comment: i tried adduser also, but unfortunately same result.

Comment: If your system's `adduser` is a Perl script and not a symlink to `useradd`, check `/etc/adduser.conf` and ensure that `FIRST_GID` is set appropriately. AMI may use `GROUP` as an alias of that, but the Ubuntu box I'm looking at now has no such definition.

Comment: i don't see any .conf file related to adduser in /etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system is configured to use **user groups** – to create a new group for each user, with the same name as the username. For example, your user `testuser2(502)` will have the primary group `testuser2(504)`.

The configuration file for `useradd` is **`/etc/login.defs`**, and this setting is controlled by the **`USERGROUPS_ENAB`** statement. You can also temporarily change this behavior by using the options `-U`/`--user-group` and `-N`/`--no-user-group`.

Remember that `useradd` and `adduser` are separate programs; the defaults set in `adduser` do not necessarily affect the simpler `useradd`.

Comment: But USERGROUPS_ENAB says "This enables userdel to remove user groups if no members exist". Is related to addition of user?

Comment: @Praveen: Yes, see manual page of `useradd`, under `-N` and `-U` options.